# MATLAB Errorbars linestyle

Tags: matlab, graphics, matlab-figure, matlab-hg2

When using MATLAB, does anyone know a way for drawing errorbars with the same style of the data line?

For example, when using:

```
d = errorbar(x,y,y_error,'Linestyle', ':');
```

MATLAB returns the data lines in dotted style, while the bars in each of the points are solid lines. How do I make the bars *also* be a dotted line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the undocumented `Bar` property of the `ErrorBar` object to set the line style:

```
d = errorbar(1:3, 1:3, 1:3, 'LineStyle', ':');

% Make the vertical bars dotted as well
d.Bar.LineStyle = 'dotted';

% Valid values include: 'solid' | 'dashed' |  'dotted' | 'dashdot' | 'none'
```

[image]

Or if you just want it to be the same as the `LineStyle` you specified you could also use the undocumented `Line` property:

```
d.Bar.LineStyle = d.Line.LineStyle
```

For future reference, you can get a list of all properties and methods for a graphics object (undocumented or not) by obtaining the [`meta.class`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meta.class.html) for the object:

```
cls = meta.class.fromName(class(d));

% List of all properties
cls.PropertyList

% List of all methods
cls.MethodList
```

You can often find and modify the various pieces of a complex plot object using undocumented properties found in this way.

Comment: I was about to answer the same! I found this undocumented property by looking into `d = errorbar(...)` by calling `struct(d)`, which reveals more about the `ErrorBar` object. There I found many properties, the first being the `d.Bar`, which is a `LineStrip`, which in turn has a `LineStyle` property that can take values `'solid' | 'dashed' | 'dotted' | 'dashdot' | 'none'`. You could add this information to your answer to elucidate the origin and how others might investigate these situations themselves.

Comment: really thank you, I didn't know about this property and now I understand why, given that it is undocumented. Very good suggerstion, thanks.

Comment: @Erik The better way to get information is via `meta.class`. Updated the answer to show how to do that.

Comment: @Transagonistica See the update which allows you to get more info and also to just match the error bar style to whatever you specify as the linestyle automatically.